# why doesn't this bootstrap layout work in jsfiddle?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, jsfiddle

Why doesn't this bootstrap layout work in jsfiddle?:

https://jsfiddle.net/1mdodv7r/2/show/

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-xs-6" 
                style="border:solid black 1px;height:200px;">Map</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="border:solid black 1px;height:200px;">
                <div style="border:solid black 1px;height:100px;width:100%;">SideViewSection1</div>
                <div style="border:solid black 1px;height:100px;width:100%;">SideViewSection2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-xs-6" 
                style="border:solid black 1px;height:200px;">MapParameters</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6" 
                style="border:solid black 1px;height:200px;display:none;">
                [Empty]
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</body>
```

It works in my local environment withoutissue.  I googled and found out that /show/ should be appended to the jsfiddle to display the view in fullscreen.  However, even in full screen mode, the bootstrap styling does not seem to be getting applied.  Is there a special trick for this or are there other sites which are better for sharing bootstrap code?

Comment: Bootstrap CSS link which added in external resources was wrong. Hope this is what you are looking for. https://jsfiddle.net/1mdodv7r/3/show/

Comment: thanks!  codepen.io seems to be more user-friendly as well as having a more modern ui.  codepen.io let me simply copy and paste my html contents directly into the html pane and it works as expected.  thanks for debugging my jsfiddle for me though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beacuse you have added URL with link tag so this is not working. Just call URL "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css"